# Multiple selections with overlapping from a vector without a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Say I have a vector `v` of length `m` in matlab. I want to extract from it some slices putting them in a new matrix. I will have a hopsize `h_size`, a window length `win_len` and a number of jumps `num_j`. How can I accomplish this without using a loop? The loop version would be:

```
for i = 1:num_j
   slice(i,:) = v(1+(i-1)*h_size : win_len+(i-1)*h_size);
end
```

Code should work with this variant of the algorithm in which I have a double for loop for all combinations of slices and hopsizes. In this case I have slices of different lengths so I will use a cell array:

```
sliceInd = 0;
for i = 1:num_j
   for j = i:num_j
      sliceInd = sliceInd + 1;
      slice{sliceInd} = v(1+(i-1)*h_size : win_len+(j-1)*h_size);
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first case, you can do this using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create your indices for you.

```
slice = v(bsxfun(@plus, 1:h_size:h_size*num_j, (0:win_len-1).').');
```

**Explanation**

What this essentially does is it identifies all of your starting positions:

```
starts = 1:h_size:(h_size * num_j);
```

Then starting from each of these locations, we want to sample `win_len` points. To do this for a given start position, we can use this formula.

```
inds = starts(k) + 0:(win_len - 1);
```

We can then use `bsxfun` to do this for *all* start locations.

```
bsxfun(@plus, 1:h_size:h_size*num_j, (0:win_len-1).').';
```

Then we use this as an index into `v` to get your final result.

This assumes that you have choosen your variables properly so that you don't try to index past the end of `v` (i.e. when `(h_size * num_j) + win_len - 1 > numel(v)`.

**Edit**

If you really need the option to loop through various `h_size` and `win_len` values, you could use nested `arrayfun` calls to get the result without looping, but this is honestly a little messy.

```
R = arrayfun(@(h,w)arrayfun(@(x)v(x+(0:w-1)), 1:h:h*num_j, 'uni', 0), hrange, wrange, 'uni', 0);
slice = cat(2, R{:});
```

You would define the range of `h_size` values in `hrange` and the `win_len` values in `wrange`.

**Edit2**

If you're trying to perform this operation on multiple rows of `v` at a time for many permutations of `h_size` and `w_len`. I would probably just loop it in this way.

```
% Anonymous function to get the indices
getinds = @(h,w)bsxfun(@plus, 1:h:h*num_j, (0:w-1).').';

% All permutations of h_size and w_len
[hh, ww] = meshgrid(hrange, wrange);

alldata = cell(size(hh));

for k = 1:numel(hh)
    inds = getinds(hh(k), ww(k));
    V = reshape(v(:, inds), [size(v, 1), size(inds)]);

    % V is a 3D array where the info for each window is along the third dim
    % i.e. Hop #1 for the first for of v is V(1,1,:)

    % Do whatever you want here

    % ... or store data in cell array for processing later
    alldata{k} = V;
end
```

Comment: Regarding the second solution, with "messy" you mean you wouldn't use it though it allows a vectorization of the operation instead of using nested loops? What if I have a matrix grouping together vectors of same length by rows (one row of the matrix is the v vector for which i want to apply slice selection) instead of one single vector? Can I still use a suitable version of your arrayfun solution avoiding iterations by rows?

Comment: @LorenzoMonni Messy is more referring to the fact that it will work fine for what you posted it just looks a little obfuscated and cryptic so someone coming after you to use your code may get confused. How many interations of `h_size` and `w_len` are you talking about doing? It may not be completely necessary to remove the loop

Comment: The single operation of slice selection just has something like nchoose(20,2) combinations, but it can be repeatd thousands of times and for each single slice I do plenty of other operations (I'm also starting to learn how the parallelization toolbox can help me).

Comment: @LorenzoMonni I think I would probably use the first part of my answer inside of a loop. I have added an edit to my answer that shows how I would probably accomplish this

Comment: Edit2 works really good, though you can't store slices coming from different lengths in the same mat, so you have to do whatever you have to do with slices inside the for loop.

Comment: @LorenzoMonni Or you could simply save `V` into a cell array within that loop. Either way should work and I think the performance should be decent.